# Parsing HTML to recreate tables in a Word Document using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, ms-word

Is there a way of taking html code for a table and printing out the same table in a word document using VBA (VBA should be able to parse the html code block for a table)?

It is possible to take the contents of the table and copy them into a new table created in Word, however is it possible to recreate a table using the html code and vba?

For any of this, where can one begin to research?

EDIT:
Thanks to R3uK: here is the first portion of the VBA script which reads a line of html code from a file and uses R3uK's code to print it to the excel worksheet:

```
Private Sub button1_Click()

    Dim the_string As String
    the_string = Trim(ImportTextFile("path\to\file.txt"))
    ' still working on removing new line characters
    Call PrintHTML_Table(the_string)

End Sub

Public Function ImportTextFile(strFile As String) As String

    ' http://mrspreadsheets.com/1/post/2013/09/vba-code-snippet-22-read-entire-text-file-into-string-variable.html
    Open strFile For Input As #1
    ImportTextFile = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1

End Function

' Insert R3uK's portion of the code here
```

Comment: I think it's possible. Though, it would involve analyzing the structure table first. Not all HTML tables are structured the same. Use MS XML 6.0 to get the data from the web page and then cast the text response of the MS XML object into a HTML document object. You'll be able to access the content of the table by getting the `<table>` tags and what's inside it.

Comment: (1) Once this would have been comparatively easy.  The table structure and the formatting would all be simple Html. Now it can be a mixture of Html and Css with the Css in another file and authors can define tables without using any of the <table> tags.  Why not open the Html file with Word?  (2) Why have you tagged this question [excel-vba] and not [word-vba]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a good place to start, you will only need to check content after to see if there is any problem and then copy it to word.

```
    Sub PrintHTML_Table(ByVal StrTable as String)
    Dim TA()

    Dim Table_String as String
    Table_String = " " & StrTable & " "

    TA = SplitTo2DArray(Table_String, "</tr>", "</td>")

    For i = LBound(TA, 1) To UBound(TA, 1)
        For j = LBound(TA, 2) To UBound(TA, 2)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = Trim(Replace(Replace(TA(i, j), "<td>", ""), "<tr>", ""))
        Next j
    Next i

    End Sub




    Public Function SplitTo2DArray(ByRef StringToSplit As String, ByRef RowSep As String, ByRef ColSep As String) As String()

        Dim Rows                    As Variant
        Dim rowNb                   As Long
        Dim Columns()               As Variant
        Dim i                       As Long
        Dim maxlineNb               As Long
        Dim lineNb                  As Long
        Dim asCells()               As String
        Dim j                       As Long

        ' Split up the table value by rows, get the number of rows, and dim a new array of Variants.
        Rows = Split(StringToSplit, RowSep)
        rowNb = UBound(Rows)
        ReDim Columns(0 To rowNb)

        ' Iterate through each row, and split it into columns. Find the maximum number of columns.
        maxlineNb = 0
        For i = 0 To rowNb
            Columns(i) = Split(Rows(i), ColSep)
            lineNb = UBound(Columns(i))
            If lineNb > maxlineNb Then
                maxlineNb = lineNb
            End If
        Next i

        ' Create a 2D string array to contain the data in <Columns>.
        ReDim asCells(0 To maxlineNb, 0 To rowNb)

        ' Copy all the data from Columns() to asCells().
        For i = 0 To rowNb
            For j = 0 To UBound(Columns(i))
                asCells(j, i) = Columns(i)(j)
            Next j
        Next i

        SplitTo2DArray = asCells()

    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the start. The Code helps for a start, however when testing it out, i added this: `Dim Table_String As String
    Table_String = "<tr><td>This</td><td>is</td></tr><tr><td>the</td><td>second row</td></tr>"` and I get the message `Compile Error: cannot assign to array` and it highlights the `TA =` portion

Comment: First, I mixed up tr and td as row and column, that it fixed now and best thing with split, add a space before and after your string. And when it's split you can trim() it to get rid of eventual useless spaces!

Comment: Made the changes, still gives the same error. I tried this on word and excel. I am calling it as such: `Call PrintHTML_Table(the_string)` in another Sub (which is for the button click).

Comment: Could it be because we aren't declaring any bounds for array TA? (or ReDim ing TA with boundaries? or is the return from the function supposed to do that?)

Comment: When Declaring `TA()`, I changed it to `TA() As String`. Now I get the error  `Run Time error 424: Object required`. The line `ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1,j+1)...` is highlighted.

Comment: For the `Object required` error, I don't see why. But try to declare `TA` and `Function SplitTo2DArray` as Variant, it might work (I totally forgot to check the function!)

Comment: And defining dimensions in that kind of use is not necessary, as when you use a split (like in function)

Comment: Changed `asCells()` to type varaint, `TA()` to type variant and `SplitTo2DArray` to type variant, it still returns the `Run Time error 424: Object required` on line `ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1,j+1)...`. This is weird

Comment: Silly question but you are running this with VBA excel? If no, you must open an excel application and the workbook first. If yes, put a break in function to spy RowNb and UBound(Columns(i)) .

Comment: I tried it on both before the changes were made. Just tried it on Excel (after the changes) and it works like a charm. Beautiful. I'm new to VBA and had a little trouble with the variable types and function calls. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome mate! You can add your full code for word here after to share it! ;)