# Convert HTML response to WORD

Tags: html, vba, ms-word

In MS Word i have a macro that sends the request to the web server, and then return the data html
My macro

```
Sub Macro1()

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

'server authorization (need)
URL = "http://example.com/search.php"
Dim loginData As String
loginData = "login=123&password=123"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.Send loginData


'request
URL = "http://example.com/search.php"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.Send ("var1=value&var2=value&var3=value")

strResponse = objHTTP.responseText
Selection.TypeText Text:= strResponse 

End Sub
```

Now in Word document my macro inserted response as simple text

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=windows-1251">
    <title>Результат поиска</title>
    <link href="css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 110%;">Search result</span>
    </div>
    <table id=result>
        <tr>
            <th>Some text</th>
            <th>Some text</th>
            <th>Some text</th>
            <th>Some text</th>
            <th>Some text</th>
            <th>Some text</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td class='leftAlign'>Some text<br>Some textSome textSome text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td class='leftAlign'>Some text<br>Some textSome textSome textSome textSome text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Please help me, how to convert my response (table id="result") in a normal WORD-table? Like this
normal Word table
[image]

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483422/parsing-html-to-recreate-tables-in-a-word-document-using-vba) may be a good place to start.

Comment: Thank Mike, but it work only in Excel macro, i don't know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the post Mike points to is a good starting point: convert the HTML table string to something Word can deal with. Word has a Range.ConvertToTable function that will transform data in a delimited text format to a table. The record (row) delimiter must be ANSI 13 (vbCr); the field (column) delimiter can be anything you like.

So: 1) Remove <tr> from the table definition; 2) replace </tr> with ANSI 13 (vbCr) and drop the last of these tags; 3) Remove <td> from the table definition; 4) Replace </td> with a field delimiter of your choice (something that's not in the field content) and drop the last of these tags.

The result will be a string that you write to the Range where you want the table in the document, then convert it to a table:

```
rng.Text = stringTableDef
Dim tbl as Word.Table
Set tbl = rng.ConvertToTable('Params here)
```

You'll want to set the first parameter - the field separator, for sure. Check the other parameters whether you want any of them, they're all optional. For your reference, here's the method documentation:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835980.aspx

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845710.aspx) should work for Microsoft Word and it also contains examples written in VBA.

I guess you've then got to find a way of parsing the HTML into the table cells.